# How to wire a small quadcopter drone with resistor and breadboard (If possible)?

Tags: drone

http://www.instructables.com/id/SpeechVoice-Controlled-Arduino-Drone/?ALLSTEPS

Hi guys!

I am following this project but I do however not have all the items currently at home so I was thinking if there is an optional solution.

I do not have any resistors or a breadboard currently at home so I was wondering if there is an optional solution.

What I have is, arduino uno + arduino mini and hc-05 bluetooth and of course 4 small drone motors. On top of this I have TIP-122 transistors and a l293d motor driver.

Could I somehow make it work with that considering i do not have resistors or a breadboard at home?

I know how to solder of course so if I need to solder wires that is not a problem. I appreciate any help very much!!

Comment: That's not a breadboard, that's a PCB.

Comment: Resistors are probably the single most basic item that every EE needs without question. A good selection of the common ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need resistors where that article puts them, otherwise you could brownout the whole thing. You may be able to get away without a PCB, at the cost of reduced stability. Find or borrow the three resistors needed for the project, and then I recommend that you order both a large pack of 1% resistors as well as a variety of PCBs when you are able to.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you won't be able to finish that project without using resistors because your Arduino mini pins at most support 40 mA (as far as I recall - please check the datasheet). Those resistors are there to limit your pin current. (However in that case, 100 ohms is too low, please use 220 ohms for your sake!)

What you can do is:

- Find some scrap electronics at home and remove the resistors
- Let this become an interesting project and do something like this: http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Power-Resistor/

Other than that, in my opinion, you can get away with not having a breadboard or PCB. Just make sure that the wires in no case touch each other (this thing will be flying and dropping for sure!) or you'll end up burning one of those chips.

Also, keep in mind that if you short that lipo battery, there is a significant risk of fire/toxic gas hazard. So I would try this outside, away from people.